# Filter by Distinct Values in Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby, apollo

I am trying to display a list of unique subject categories on a Gatsby site, which I will use to create unique pages. These will serve as taxonomy terms, of sorts. A limited version of my source json file looks like:

```
  [
    {
    "BookID": "4176",
    "Title": "Book Title 1",
    "Subject": {
      "subjectID": "HR",
      "name": "Civil War & Reconstruction"
    }
},
  {
    "BookID": "3619",
    "Title": "Book Title 2",
    "Subject": {
      "subjectID": "AR",
      "name": "Fine Art & Photography"
    }
    
   
  },
  {
    "BookID": "3619",
    "Title": "Book Title 3",
    "Subject": {
      "subjectID": "AR",
      "name": "Fine Art & Photography"
    }
  }
]
```

In my gatsby-node.js file, I can create pages using a list of distinct values of IDs to serve as the slugs to create my subject categories. As below:

```
allSubjects: allBooksJson {
          distinct(field: Subject___subjectID)
        }
```

However, I also need the name associated with these. I have not yet seen a way to use this as a filter, in order to deduplicate the results of a query.

So what I would ultimately like to is return all the unique subject objects so I can use the subjectID as a slug and the full name where needed on the individual pages.

Still learning Gatsby, so this may be the wrong approach, and any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: gatsby source plugin should create 'reverse relationships' ... should be possible to query allSubjects (limited to distinct ids from earlier separate query) and related books inside - check gatsby playground ... code ... you can filter main datasource (just like filtering array in js) or collect required data within createPage loop in `gatsby-node.js` ... it depends on requirements

Comment: Thanks! I will check that out

Comment: Apologies, I don't think I communicated the right question. I can make a new post if that's the practice, but somebody might find the given help very useful. I am able to get the names on the individual subject pages, but it's just printing out a list of all the unique subjects as links, using both the ids as slugs and names. I'm not yet sure if this is too far from what I related, so I will accept the answer and if necessary create a new post to not be additionally confusing.

Comment: just update the question with info about shape of data you want - example instead of [a bit missleading] description

Comment: I think I can actually work with what you all have given me, and don't want to (additionally) confuse anyone else who needs something close to what I asked for by reforming the question. Sorry to muddle up my first post, I shouldn't have attempted in the middle of a mental burnout! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The idea of creating dynamic pages, is to get all the needed values in your `gatsby-node.js` using a GraphQL query, to create a bunch of pages and then, use the context to send a unique identifier to the template, to filter again the pages to get the specific data for each entry (books in your case). So:

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)


exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allBookJson {
        edges {
          node {
            Subject{
              subjectID
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.allBookJson.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: `books/${node.Subject.subjectID}`, // change it as you wish
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/book.js`), // change it as you wish
      context: {
        subjectID: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

*Note: adapt the snippet (query, loop, and variables) to your needs. You don't need to filter anything at this point, since you are only fetching the `subjectID` of all books.*

If the values are likely to be repeated, use the [`new Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove the duplicates, then, you can loop through them to create pages dynamically:

```
let unique = [...new Set(result.data.allBookJson.edges.node)];
```

You are sending the `subjectID` to your `templates/book.js` file via context, so it will be available to be used as a `pageContext`.

Anytime you want just to get a list of all books, you can create a page query or a static query and loop through them at any time.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default function Book({ data }) {
  const books = data.allBookJson
  
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        {books.map(book=>{
          return <div>book.title</div>
        })}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query($subjectID: String) {
    allBookJson(Subject___subjectID: { eq: $subjectID } ) {
       edges{
         node{
           title
         }
       }
    }
  }
`
```

*Note: again, test your query and adapt it to your needs at `localhost:8000/___graphql`. If you have duplicate results use the `new Set`.*

It's difficult to guess your data structure without knowing it properly, the idea is to create a unique query based on the context value `subjectID` and filter the values. Use the GraphQL playground as support to know how the query and the filters should look like.

Further details: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-seven/

Comment: question was about list/index of subjects (like tags)

Comment: You are free to provide an answer @xadm :) . He needs to supply `I am trying to display a list of unique subject categories on a Gatsby site` (hence the `new Set` provided) and `I also need the name associated with these` (hence the context API)

Comment: query returns a list/array/edges (books with the same subject) ... it requires `.map` in render/template/FC

Comment: not [enough] fixed ;) ... Map won't deduplicate on nested prop (subject), we can assume books are unique at start (maybe for json file/mistake)

Comment: That's why the `new Set` is useful

Comment: I meant Set (not Map, can't edit comment after 5min.) ... 2nd/3rd `title`s are different (`id`s are the same, by mistake probably), still won't be deduplicated

Comment: The duplicated ids are a mistake  -- sorry -- I was trying to mimic a sample from a large dataset. Books are all unique, they just can share the same subject categories. I can grab the data for the books on their own pages and even the books associated with the categories on the individual subject pages, I just need a list of all the subjects names with their ids (used as slugs to the subject pages) for broader pages. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear on that -- I will investigate all the above and see if I can use it! Thanks a lot to both of you